# Как обработать исключение?

Tags: java, android

```
try { 
    //в этом блоке мы пишем код, где может возникнуть ошибка
}catch(Exception e){ 
    // тут если выскакивает ошибка мы пишем код, который должен выполнится и Приложение закрывается??
}finally { 
    //код который выполнится независимо от того, будет ли исключение или не будет.
}
```

Т.Е если вылетело исключение, то сначала выполняется код из блока `catch`, а потом из `finally`

Если исключение не вылетело, то выполняется код, из блока `finally` ?

Как я правильно понимаю, т.е для того, чтобы Приложение не закрывалось при ошибке, то нужно сделать все , чтобы прекратить эту ошибку в блоке `catch`, и продолжить выполнение кода программы в блоке `finally`?

Comment: В целом да, но можно и без finally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В try находится код, в котором может произойти Exception.

В блоке catch(..) находится код, который каким-то образом обработает ошибку (возможно и закроет приложение или Activity, если это необходимо)

Блок finally вызывается всегда (и когда произошла ошибка, и когда не произошла).
try, catch можно реализовывать без блока finally.

Блоков catch может быть больше, чем один. Под каждую ошибку - свой блок, например:

```
try{ code...}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) { code... }
catch (IOExeption e){ code... }
finally { code... }
```

Это необходимо для того, чтобы разные ошибки обрабатывать необходимым для них образом.

Comment: Пример плохой т.к. `FileNotFoundException` никогда не закатчится будучи `extends IOException`( update: ответ изменен, притензия снимается ). + раз уж такой ответ можно упомянуть try с ресурсами

Comment: @AndreyM спасибо за замечание. Изменил порядок кетчей, теперь FileNotFoundException будет отлавливаться.